# Strange behaviour when Ordering by dynamic count AngularJS -

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to order this list of exercises by count, this works on first load, but when you start to click the increase or decrease, it increases/decreases the count of other indexes

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="exercise in exercises  | orderBy:'count' ">
              <div class="exercise-icon col-xs-2"> <img ng-src="{{ exercise.icon }}" /></div>

              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p class="exercise-name"> {{ exercise.name }} </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-4 counters">
                <span class="decrease" ng-click="decrease($index)">-</span>
                <span class="count">{{ exercise.count }} </span>
                <span class="increase" ng-click="increase($index)">+</span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**JS - Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.exercises = [
    {
      icon: 'img/pushup.jpg',
      name: 'Pushups',
      count: 20
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/squat.jpg',
      name: 'Squats',
      count: 15
    },
    {
      icon: 'img/pullup.jpg',
      name: 'Pullups',
      count: 10
    },
...


 $scope.increase = function(index) { 

                      $scope.exercises[index].count += 1; 
                    };
 $scope.decrease = function(index) { 
                 if ( ($scope.exercises[index].count) > 0){
                      $scope.exercises[index].count -= 1;
                     }
                 };
```

Comment: Can you provide `increase` and `decrease` function too?

Comment: @Michelem ok added in OP now

Comment: Like @Anik said better to pass the entire object

Comment: @user1937021 i tried out the code and it works fine. there might be something else breaking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using `$index` pass object itself

Like this

```
<span class="decrease" ng-click="decrease(exercise)">-</span>
```

JS

```
$scope.decrease=function(exercise){
  exercise.count--;
}
```

Comment: not the way to go. you are increasing overhead by passing object copies when you just need the index.

Comment: @Saksham $index won't work correctly if new scope imposed in the ng-repeat. that's why you can't rely on $index .

Comment: but in this case, you can and the code works perfectly fine for me

Comment: We should use/suggest the things which will support for long run not for certain case :) @Saksham

Comment: your answer does not mention it as a suggestion. update your answer. the code is fine and if you want to suggest, put it as a comment